# Meteor.Collection.ObjectID() vs MongoDB ObjectId()

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Why does Meteor.js use it's own algorithms for IDs?

Why doesn't it use MongoDB's ObjectId()?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Meteor uses the same method for object id's if you choose to use it:

`Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()` is the same as MongoDB's `ObjectID`

Its just under the `Meteor.Collection` name. It uses EJSON to hold object id's in ordinary JSON to the client end. Because basically there are 2 databases with meteor

**Minimongo**

This is a sort of cache of mongodb on the client end. The data is downloaded from the main mongodb on the server to this one when the browser loads up. When changes are made they are pushed up to the server.

**Server MongoDB**

This is the original mongodb from 10gen on the server

So because of these two databases Meteor needs to wrap mongodb functionality in `Meteor.Collection` and let you use the same code on both the client and server.

By default meteor won't use Object IDs it'll use sort of random alphanumeric text. This is done so you can easily use ID's in your URL's and ID's in your html attributes.

If you do use `new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()` you will get an `ObjectID` object that will use mongodb's specification of ObjectID on the server end. The timestamp value in the Object ID isn't held up but this shouldn't really do any harm.

Comment: I wasted a good 20 minutes trying to figure out why the regex `/^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/` was returning `false` with my ObjectIds... You mention Meteor uses "random alphanumeric text", is there any logic to test whether a given string is a valid ID?

Comment: @BradM you could try checking for `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{17}$/` could work. Its also not completely alphanumeric, ive never seen 0 or 1 in an _id. I think numbers than can be visually mixed up like l and 1 aren't used.

Answer (score 5):

Since 0.9.1 Meteor suggesting to use `Mongo.ObjectID` instead of `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID` . Basically both are same.
Check [history.md](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#backwards-compatible-renames) for more changes in naming conventions.

Comment: Yeah, saw this, but had a hard time figuring out how to just get the _id string. Used the following. `var newID = new Mongo.ObjectID;
item._id = newID._str;`

Thanks to this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236685/how-do-i-use-new-meteor-collection-objectid-in-my-mongo-queries-with-meteor