# How do I use new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID() in my mongo queries with meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Collection that has documents with an array of nested objects. 
Here is fixture code to populate the database:

```
if (Parents.find().count() == 0) {
    var parentId = Parents.insert({
        name: "Parent One"
    });
    Children.insert({
        parent: parentId,
        fields: [
            {
                _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(),
                position: 3,
                name: "three"
            },
            {
                _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(),
                position: 1,
                name: "one"
            },
            {
                _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(),
                position: 2,
                name: "two"
            },

        ]
    });
}
```

You might be asking yourself, why do I even need an ObjectID when I can just update based off of the names. This is a simplified example to a much more complex schema that I'm currently working on and the the nested object are going to be created dynamically, the ObjectID's are definitely going to be necessary to make this work.

Basically, I need a way to save those nested objects with a unique ID and be able to update the fields by their _id.

Here is my Method, and the call I'm making from the browser console:

```
Meteor.methods({
  upChild: function( options ) {
        console.log(new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID());
        Children.update({_id: options._id, "fields._id": options.fieldId }, {$set: {"fields.$.position": options.position}}, function(error){
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log("success");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My call from the console:

```
Meteor.call('upChild', {
  _id: "5NuiSNQdNcZwau92M",
  fieldId: "9b93aa1ef3868d762b84d2f2",
  position: 1
});
```

And here is a screenshot of the html where I'm rendering all of the data for the Parents and Children collections:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just an observation, as I was looking how generate unique IDs client side for a similar reason. I found calling new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID() was returning a object in the form 'ObjectID("abc...")'. By assigning Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()._str to _id, I got string as 'abc...' instead, which is what I wanted.

I hope this helps, and I'd be curious to know if anyone has a better way of handling this?

Jason

Comment: I don't have a better way of handling this, and am in OP's situation of having to generate unique IDs each array entry.

Doing this worked for me, but I think "new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()" checks for ID uniqueness, and just translating the generated string into a str object might bypass the uniqueness check, causing problems with large DBs in the future.

Not looking to scale my project so this works for now, but it might be problematic for large projects.

Comment: So, is there a way to ensure the uniqueness of the id while storing a string form of the generated id?

Comment: This worked for me as my application also had to work offline so there was no way of guaranteeing uniqueness against the server all the time. The Meteor documentation for the routine used (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random) implies that the standard code is *likely* to be globally unique. However, you might want to consider an alternative method if you're likely to be generating millions of records.

Answer (score 12):

Avoid using the _str because it can change in the future. Use this:

`new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().toHexString()` or

`new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().valueOf()`

You can also use the official [random package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/random):

`Random.id()`