# Manual Reference - ObjectId()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am looking for some help with _id in Mongo. I want to manually set an ObjectId() reference but I cannot do it. I checked out the code in the official mongo documentation and inserted it in my app but fails. If someone can provide some insight I would def appreciate it. The original_id variable is what I am trying to set. Here is a link to the mongo docs - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references and the code is below. Any help/insight would be great.

```
Template.postNewJob.events({
       'submit form': function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           original_id = ObjectId();
           var position = $('[name=position]').val();
           var jobDescription = $('[name=jobDescription]').val();
           var createdAt = new Date();
           var createdBy = Meteor.userId();
           postedJobs.insert({
               _id: original_id,
               position: position,
               jobDescription: jobDescription,
               createdAt: createdAt,
               createdBy: createdBy
           });
           Router.go('dashboard');
       }
    });
```

Comment: what does "I cannot do it" means? Add the error if you get any or explain what is the result that you are getting.

Comment: @AminJ - "I cannot do it" means if i declare something like original_id = ObjectId();  - it will not set the variable with a new object ID. Also, the error I am getting is "Uncaught ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined" - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I needed to set it in the following way:
var original_id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().valueOf();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ObjectId()`, you may need to use `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()` instead.

See [Meteor.Collection.ObjectID() vs MongoDB ObjectId()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318184/meteor-collection-objectid-vs-mongodb-objectid) for more details into this.

Answer (score 0):

```
> meteor shell
Welcome to the server-side interactive shell!

Tab completion is enabled for global variables.

Type .reload to restart the server and the shell.
Type .exit to disconnect from the server and leave the shell.
Type .help for additional help.

> Coll = new Mongo.Collection('coll')
```

Default insert, Meteor will generate _id

```
> Coll.insert({str: "blah"})  
'JTeBKdTErXWQyedMN'
```

Insert passing ObjectID object as _id

```
> Coll.insert({_id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(), str: "blah"}) 
{ [String: '8dbfd702d76d6152685e2f66'] _str: '8dbfd702d76d6152685e2f66' }
```

Insert using user constructed String as _id

```
> Coll.insert({_id: "1234", str: "blah"})
'1234'
```

Of course if you create your own _id values, you are responsible for ensuring the _ids do not already exist in the collection, or your inserts will be rejected:

```
> Coll.insert({_id: "1234", str: "blah"})
WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.coll.$_id_ dup key: { : \"1234\" }","op":{"_id":"1234","str":"blah"}})
... more stack trace follows
```

And following this your collection looks like:

```
> Coll.find({}).fetch()
[ { _id: 'JTeBKdTErXWQyedMN', str: 'blah' },
  { _id: { [String: '8dbfd702d76d6152685e2f66'] _str: '8dbfd702d76d6152685e2f66' },
    str: 'blah' },
  { _id: '1234', str: 'blah' } ]

> Coll.findOne('JTeBKdTErXWQyedMN')
{ _id: 'JTeBKdTErXWQyedMN', str: 'blah' }

> Coll.findOne('1234')
{ _id: '1234', str: 'blah' }

> Coll.findOne(new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID('8dbfd702d76d6152685e2f66'))
{ _id: { [String: '8dbfd702d76d6152685e2f66'] _str: 8dbfd702d76d6152685e2f66' }, str: 'blah' }
```